# Develop apps without license on iOS 5.1.1/6.0 and Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, xcode, licensing

I'm trying to run an app that I've made on my iPhone 4 with iOS 5.1.1 and Xcode 4.5. When I try to run, it says a code sign error. I don't have a developer license but I was able to run apps on iOS 5.0.1 and Xcode 4.2.1... So, did Apple resolved the bug that can be used for installing apps?

Comment: To run applications on your phone, you need a developer licence. Without it, you need to use the simulator.

Comment: Have you tried having your device connected to your computer?

Comment: I don't have a license but on iOS 5.0 I was able to run apps on my iPhone. Simply modifying SDKsettings.plist

Answer (score 1):

Without a developer license, you should not be able to run your code on your device.